# Google maps direction from one start point to multiple end point

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a start point coordinate on Map. I have multiple(100) endpoints to calculate the total distance from start point to end points.
The start point is my office and end points are my customer's location. I want to calculate total distances.

I use for loop on javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < destinations.length; i++) {

    var request = {
        origin: "60.758447, 69.385923",
        destination: destinations[i],
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            totalKM = totalKM + (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000);
            distanceInput.value = totalKM;
            console.log(totalKM)
        }
    });

};
```

But this loop works only 10 destinations. I can see this in the console log. Does google restrict the query limit?

Comment: You are correct, Google does indeed limit the amount of `directionService` calls you can do in quick succession. [Check here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#usageLimits) for how many you can do. If you check outside of your `if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) ` I'm sure the status will be `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` or something similar.

Comment: If you only need the driving distance, try the distance matrix.

Comment: Yes I only need distance sum.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the comments posted, the distance matrix API was mentioned. I would recommend this, because you have only one origin and multiple destinations. With the directions API you can only have one origin and destination pair, but with the distance matrix API you can have multiple destination as well as origins. The distance matrix API also allows for 100 elements per request(number_of_elements = number_of_origins * number_of_destinations). This would allow you to have one origin and 100 destinations in one request. Please see usage limits here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits

When you get a response from the API, you can get the distance of each element with:

```
for(i = 0; i < response.rows[0].elements.length; i++){
    totalDistance += response.rows[0].elements[i].distance.value;
}
```

It's element 0 in the rows array since you only have one origin, if you have multiple origins, you will need to loop through multiple rows.

I have also modified one of the Google Distance Matrix API samples in the documentation to sum up the distances of 3 destination from one origin just to demo how this would work. The only difference is in your app you would have more destinations, but the logic should be the same. Please note that I took my API key out of this fiddle for security, please input your own for the sample to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/o0wyq4bo/1/

I hope this helps!